# How to parse html response with rest-assured?

Tags: html, xml, rest-assured

I get a html response when making a GET request to certain url. I want to extract some values from html response

```
<span>
    <input type="hidden" id="authId" name="authId" value="erwerwwwererewwww"/>
</span>
```

want to get the value for authId. Tried with htmlPath() and xmlPath() but not sure how to get the path value.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<Code to get ValidatableResponse>.htmlPath().getString("html.body.span.input.@value")
```